# Mails are not sent using mutt on command line

Tags: email, ubuntu, mutt

I tried to send e-mails using mutt on commande line

```
echo "File encoding finished on $Now_dmY, with some errors ffmpeg: $ffmpeg MP4Box: $mp4box Thumb: $thumb Rsync: $rsync" | mutt -s "[Failed] Encoding File" -- foo@bar.com
```

The result is:

```
/root/sent is not a mailbox.
Could not send the message.
You have mail in /var/mail/root
```

When I opened the root file:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
--A1DA321EB7.1563969927/ns366860.ip-94-23-8.eu
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822
```

Thank you

Comment: Please attach your mutt configuration file. Something is not correct. Your `echo ...` command is working like a charm.

Comment: this is the 2 lines I found in .muttrc `set from = "user@domain.com"
set realname = "Realname of the user"`

Comment: Please have a read how to configure mutt. There's missing some configuration :)

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue with the "sent" file.
Turned out that the file permissions somehow "changed" from 600 to 611 and that inhibited the operation.
We renamed the file so mutt would create a new file and it worked fine and that's had we figured out that the permissions changed.
We would never had though to try that if not for the info above!
Thanks everyone on this site!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-e 'unset record'` to your mutt command.
It's similar question to [Mutt failing as cron job with 'Couldn't lock /sent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037545/mutt-failing-as-cron-job-with-couldnt-lock-sent)

Answer (score 0):

I preferred adding `unset record` at the end of .muttrc configuration file.