# Mutt failing as cron job with 'Couldn't lock /sent'

Tags: cron, root, mutt

I have a bash script which picks up files from /tmp and emails them to me. I run this script as root and it works perfectly but I am trying to get this automated with crontab.

Added the job to crontab, again running as root, and now I get 'Couldn't lock /sent'.

I managed to confirm it's using the file in /root by changing it's name in Muttrc and tried permission at 600 and 777.

(Also getting an error Segmentation fault, hoping that will go away if I fix the above.)

Anyone any ideas why Mutt is different as a cron job with the same user and the same file.

I simplified the script as follows and is doing exactly the same, works from root shell, but not in crontab.
error:-

```
Couldn't lock /sent
/data/mediators/email_file: line 5:  1666 Segmentation fault      mutt $email -s "test" -i /tmp/test.txt < /dev/null
```

email_file script:-

```
#!/bin/bash
email=——@——.com
mutt $email -s "test" -i /tmp/test.txt < /dev/null
```

crontab:-

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=——@—-.com
HOME=/

54 02 * * * root /data/mediators/email_file
```

I also added printenv to the job and compared to a server where this runs OK. The difference is that the working system has USER=root, whereas the non-working one does not show this variable as being set.

Comment: Without the script we can't help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is combination of `HOME=/` env variable in crontab and default mutt **record** configuration which defaults to *~/sent*.

mutt stores sent emails in the record file. So choose whether you want to keep them (fix crontab's env var **HOME** or set mutt's **record** to meaningful value.

Add this option to mutt command in **email_file** If you want to set it:

`-e 'set record=/root/sent'`

or unset it with:

`-e 'unset record'`

You can find more in man pages [muttrc(5)](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#record)

```
record

Type: path
Default: “~/sent”

This specifies the file into which your outgoing messages should be appended. (This is meant as the primary method for saving a copy of your messages, but another way to do this is using the “my_hdr” command to create a “Bcc:” field with your email address in it.)

The value of $record is overridden by the $force_name and $save_name variables, and the “fcc-hook” command. Also see $copy and $
```